# Constrained Window render error

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Basically we have two problems and they may depend so [Here is the link to the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074598/position-a-constrained-window-relative-from-the-center-and-top-of-the-constraini):

We tried the constrained [border layout example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/layout/border.html) from the API with the difference of setting `autoShow: true` which ends in a broken window rendered to the top left of the document.

How can this be fixed and where is the error?

Comment: I had the same problem. The reason was that the window had no size defined.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Thanks for the comment but the window actually has a height and width set.

Comment: I think @sra is correct with his explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are facing the problem that the constraining container didn't finished the layout yet so that the window failed to layout itself by using the constrain target. I recommend you to call [setVisible(true)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-setVisible) on the window by using the [afterFirstLayout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.panel-method-afterFirstLayout) method. The method is documented as private but based on the usage within the framework itself it should better be promoted as protected template, so you should be save using it.

I guess the `afterRender` wouldn't be enough cause the layout hadn't be processed yet. And the `afterLayout` template method would run more then once.

You may give it a try.

Comment: Ok, it took us some time to figure out that we need to save the window instance in a separate collection because the reference from the items collection get removed. But after that it worked. Thanks on that topic!!