# Position a constrained Window relative from the center and top of the constraining container

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

We need to position a constrained Window (like in this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/layout/border.html)) relative from the top and the center of the container where it is constrained to. But in the config we only found x and y which would require to calculate the center on each document change.

Isn't there any other way to archive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

[alignTo() docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-alignTo)

```
alignTo(element, [position], [offsets], [animate] )
```

> Aligns the element with another element relative to the specified
>   anchor points. If the other element is the document it aligns it to
>   the viewport. The position parameter is optional, and can be specified
>   in any one of the following formats:
>
> Blank: Defaults to aligning the element's top-left corner to the
>   target's bottom-left corner ("tl-bl"). One anchor (deprecated): The
>   passed anchor position is used as the target element's anchor point.
>   The element being aligned will position its top-left corner (tl) to
>   that point. This method has been deprecated in favor of the newer two
>   anchor syntax below. Two anchors: If two values from the table below
>   are passed separated by a dash, the first value is used as the
>   element's anchor point, and the second value is used as the target's
>   anchor point. In addition to the anchor points, the position parameter
>   also supports the "?" character. If "?" is passed at the end of the
>   position string, the element will attempt to align as specified, but
>   the position will be adjusted to constrain to the viewport if
>   necessary. Note that the element being aligned might be swapped to
>   align to a different position than that specified in order to enforce
>   the viewport constraints. Following are all of the supported anchor
>   positions... for more info see the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-alignTo)

or

[anchorTo() docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-anchorTo)

```
anchorTo(element, [position], [offsets], [animate], [monitorScroll], [callback])
```

> Anchors an element to another element and realigns it when the window is resized.

*Edit*

If you do something of this in a early state the positioning may fail. I would try to add a delay to the alignment by using [Ext.Function.createDelayed](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-createDelayed). Try something between 10-50 as delay.

Example:

```
Ext.Function.createDelayed(windowRef.anchorTo,50)(Ext.getBody(),'t-t',[-100,0]);
```

Comment: This didn't work. We tried `alignTo(contrainingRef,'t-t',[-100,0])`, `alignTo(Ext.getBody(),'t-t',[-100,0])`, `anchorTo(contrainingRef,'t-t',[-100,0])` and `anchorTo(Ext.getBody(),'t-t',[-100,0])` in the afterFirstLayout method you recommend us in the linked question. We tried it before setVisible() and after. None of them changed the alignment of the window.

Comment: @JJR See my edit. I guess you will need a delay so that the layout has time to finish calculation (just a guess).

Comment: That fixed time delay is pretty fragile.  Have you tried doing the positioning in an afterlayout event listener of the container you are putting the window inside?

Comment: @MacyAbbey Yes, I am doing this inside the afterFirstLayout method of the container (cause I want it to run only once). But that didn't worked. With the suggested delay it worked.

Comment: @MacyAbbey Based on your hint my colleague also tried to add it to the window afterrender and afterlayout event but with no luck. So the delay seems to be the only way to get it to work :(

Comment: Quite odd, it would have to also be after the layout of the component which is constraining the window.  On a side note, if you read the docs on the window class, it claims that if you leave x and y undefined, the window should default to showing in the center of its containing element. So perhaps try adding the window with no x and y to its parent after the parent has finished laying out.

Answer (score 1):

I think Ext.window.Window's `showBy` method provides the easiest way to do this as it doesn't require the window to be rendered, etc. before it can be applied.  A solution that uses the body of the app as the parent container looks like this:

```
let appBody = Ext.getBody();
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'window'
}).showBy(appBody, 't-t', [-100, 0])
```

See the Ext docs for more info on the `showBy` method (here are links for Ext [4](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-method-showBy) and [6](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-showBy))